# Can I setup virtual environments for different python versions?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, django

I need to setup local webserver that serves several django apps and I have comparatively little linux (lubuntu 18.04) experience. Problem is that one of these apps are written in python2 and others are python3. My question is whether is this possible to run on the following single system: I install nginx+db and then setup virtual environments for different python versions. Into those, I install django, wsgi (whatever is most suitable, gunicorn?) and database interfaces. Is this workable situation? Is there a better way to set this up?

Comment: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv, or you could containerize with something like Docker.